# jCycle prev/next functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcycle

I'm working on a small project. I'm wondering if there is a way with jcycle to keep the prev button visibile if you're on slide 1, but when on that slide, it won't allow you to go backwards. The same needs to work with the next button. If you're on the last slide, the button is visible, but you can't proceed back to slide 1. I hope this all makes sense. If anyone knows of examples or links that have what I'm looking for, that would be great.

Thanks.

Addition

here's my function currently:

```
function onAfter(curr, next, opts){
            var index = opts.currSlide;
            $('.prev')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
            $('.next')[index == opts.slideCount -1 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
        }
```

I don't want to show/hide the buttons. I just want to "disable" them but have them show. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own prev/next links with some valid selector and set the after callback which will not do anything. Generally in `after` callback we show/hide the prev/next links conditionally by checking the index of the current slide. Try this

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    prev:   '#prev', 
    next:   '#next', 
    after:   function(){}, 
    timeout: 0 
});
```